# Connect to go daddy hosted Database using php connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, post

i keep getting a 500 internal server error when trying to submit my form. The Database is hosted in godaddy.com. I think i have hostname wrong. here is my code.

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME','Survey'); 
define('DB_USER','BC'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','*********'); 
define('DB_HOST','50.62.209.72.secureserver.net');
$link = mysql_connect('DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD'); 
if(!$link) {    
   die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error()); 
} 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if(!$db_selected){ 
   die('Can\'t use '. DB_name . ':' .mysql_error()); 
}

/*echo 'Connected Successfully';*/
$value  = $_POST['last']; 
$value2 = $_POST['first']; 
$value3 = $_POST['phone']; 
$value4 = $_POST['email']; 
$value5 = $_POST['fax']; 
$value6 = $_POST['company'];
 $sql   = "INSERT INTO crofton (last, first, Phone, Email, Fax, Company) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')"; 
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {   
   die('Error: '. mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the specific error that's happening. (Check the server logs perhaps, or turn on display errors temporarily:
http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Answer (score 0):

yes your host name is wrong, [Read Viewing Your Database's Details](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/39/viewing-your-databases-details) to know more about godaddy Database Details